# Angular-UI Routing - how do I pass a url parameter, non-url parameter and link to a subview

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I've been fiddling around with this for ages and can't figure it our from the docs. I want to pass a parameter, data, which has the job data. I want to pass an ID so that the page can be deep linked as well. I also want it to go to `careers/job/1234`. Anyone know how this works?

```
  .state('career', {
    url:'/career',
    templateUrl: 'views/career.html',
    controller: 'CareerCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'career'
  })
  .state('job', {
    url:'/career/job/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/job.html',
    controller: 'JobCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'job',
    params: {
      data: {}
    }
  })

  <a ui-sref="job/{{job.id}}({ data: job })">{{job.title}}</a>
  <!-- doesnt work -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ui-sref="job({id: job.id,data:job})
```

Comment: data is specified in params?